# Change PieChart in docx file using apache POI

Tags: java, apache

I have a 3D pie chart in my docx file. I want to change the pie chart data useing POI , the following is my code. I can get the chart xml data, but how can I save it to the docx?

```
            OPCPackage docx = XWPFDocument.openPackage("test2.docx");
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(docx);
        List<POIXMLDocumentPart> parts = document.getRelations();

        for (POIXMLDocumentPart part : parts){
            if("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml".equalsIgnoreCase(part.getPackagePart().getContentType())){
                PackagePart pkg = part.getPackagePart();
                ChartSpaceDocument cht = ChartSpaceDocument.Factory.parse(pkg.getInputStream());
                CTChartSpace chtSpc = cht.getChartSpace();
                CTPieChart pieChart = chtSpc.getChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0);
            }

        }
```